# undefined reference to `function'

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference

For some reason the program is giving me this error

`undefined reference to createNetworkDriver`

Right now my folder structure is:

```
mini-kernel/
            kernel/
                   drivers/
                           network/
                                   network.h
                                   network.c
           util/
                errors/
                       errors.c
           main.c
```

network.h:

```
#ifndef _network_h_
#define _network_h_
#pragma once

#include <stdbool.h>
#include<stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    bool initalized;
    int32_t status;
    int (*initalize)(void);
}NetworkDriver;

NetworkDriver* createNetworkDriver(void);
NetworkDriver* destroyNetworkDriver(NetworkDriver *self);
#endif
```

network.c:

```
#include "network.h"
#include "../../../util/errors/errors.c"

extern void die(const char *message);

NetworkDriver* createNetworkDriver(void)
{
    printf("Working");
    NetworkDriver nd = malloc(sizeof(NetworkDriver));
}

NetworkDriver* destroyNetworkDriver(NetworkDriver *self)
{
    if(self->initalized == true)
        free(self);
    else
        die("NET_DRIVER FAILED TO DESTROY");

}
```

errors.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

void die(const char *message)
{
    if(errno) {
        perror(message);
    } else {
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", message);
    }

    exit(1);
}
```

And finally my main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "kernel/drivers/network/network.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NetworkDriver *nd = createNetworkDriver();
}
```

And for some reason when i run the `main.c` file `gcc main.c -std=c99 -w -lm` , i get the error: `undefined reference to createNetworkDriver`.

Im currently programming this online [here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/mini-kernel).

Comment: You must build with all source files.

Comment: In your network.h #include<stdint.h> lacks space after include and probably this why it's not included and not compiled?

Comment: Sorry @JoachimPileborg im a newb here. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @RobertNavado: No, the space is not required (though IMHO it does look a bit better with it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build with *all* source files. Just including a header file is not enough for the compiler and linker to know which files you really need.

So do something like this instead:

```
$ gcc main.c util/errors/errors.c kernel/drivers/network/network.c -std=c99 -o my_kernel -w -lm
```

This will build each source file into a (temporary) object file and link all the object files together into a single executable file named `my_kernel` (specified using the `-o` option).

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot! Nvm knew about this.. Btw this why using Makefiles are the best! Cause there are gonna be tons of C Files! But is there any alternative than listing all C files?

Comment: @Dsafds It doesn't matter if you're using makefiles or cmake or any IDE or something else, sooner or later you need to list all source files in one form or another.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, but sometimes the "list" can be something like `*.c`.

Comment: @KeithThompson what do you mean? easier way to do this?

Comment: @Dsafds: For example, you can compile all the C files in the current directory with `gcc -c *.c`. You can also use wildcards in a Makefile.

Comment: But that would be kinda dangerous.. ABout if i dont want a specific .c file to compile... One more question Keith, can i define a struct function? like as you see there is a function inside struct NetworkDrivers called initalize.. How do i define it so it actually does something? Thankyou

Comment: Forget to mention so you see lol @KeithThompson . look above comment please sir

Comment: If you don't want to compile all the `*.c` files, then don't specify `*.c`. (But if you don't want to compile it, why is it there?) No, you can't define a function inside a structure (you can in C++). `initialize` is a *pointer* to a function, and it has to be initialized to point to some function defined elsewhere.